# SoundCloud track delete error

Tags: soundcloud

I am trying to delete a track on SoundCloud, when I click the trash button and delete it goes away visibly temporarily followed by this notification in the top right corner of the browser window:

> Oops!
>   Record Duplicate un-reverted deletion soundcloud:deletions:76460086 for Track/224050794 found!

When I reload the page a few minutes later, the song is back on my profile.

Anybody know what this and how I can get around it?

Comment: Are you using the API, or just the web application? The latter is off-topic here, since it is not a programming issue.

Comment: Here are [some previous reports](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Record+Duplicate+un-reverted+deletion+soundcloud) of the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.. If you are not able to delete a track on soundcloud, try logging in from your mobile device on soundcloud app, and then try deleting the same. It may work.. :)

Answer (score 0):

I also had a same issue.. Sometime Sound-cloud services API or Web services don`t work properly. You just try after some time.It will work :-)